# Title does not appear when LaTeX code is compiled

Tags: titles

I use Texmaker 4.0.1 to write LaTeX code. I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{test}
some text
\end{document}
```

I saved it with the name `test.tex` and compiled it with pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> -> <kbd>F6</kbd> -> <kbd>F2</kbd> -> <kbd>F9</kbd> in succession. When I press <kbd>F7</kbd> (View PDF) I see no title in the pdf but only "some text" that is, title does not appear.

Later, I have written the following code and saved it with name `test1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,onecolumn,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{some title}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> -> <kbd>F6</kbd> -> <kbd>F2</kbd> -> <kbd>F9</kbd> in succession, the following message appears,

> test1.dvi -> test1.pdf ** ERROR ** Could not open specified DVI file: test1.dvi Output file removed.

And neither dvi or pdf file is made.

I use Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7.

Comment: to make a title you need `\maketitle` where you want the title to appear (`\title`, `\author` just save the information)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make a title you need `\maketitle` where you want the title to appear.(`\title`, `\author` just save the information for use by `\maketitle`)