# Adding separate title in the Appendix environment

Tags: titles, appendices

I would like to add the title of a document that is an appendix. How can I do it? If I run this code, the title is not displayed.

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Title\footnote{Disclaimer.}}
\author{XX\thanks{University.}}
\begin{appendix}
\section{The game}
\label{unilateral}
blah
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to issue `\maketitle` in order for `\title` (and friends) to be realised.

Comment: Are you asking about adding a title to an appendix, or just adding the title to a document that [has] an appendix?

Comment: So... `\maketitle` answers your question? If so, then this is a possible duplicate: [Title does not appear when LaTeX code is compiled](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155585/5764)

Comment: Side note: remove the space in `10 pt`. Or omit the whole thing since it is default.